# How could Harry and Ron bypass Hogwarts' security in a flying Ford Anglia?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

How could Harry and Ron so easily fly Mr. Weasley's car (the magically enhanced Ford Anglia) to Hogwarts, when many times in the book it is mentioned that Hogwarts is protected by various spells, such that even Dumbledore had to revert all the security spells in *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* so that Harry and Dumbledore could enter Hogwarts on a broomstick?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**The evidence points that there were no restrictions or preventative spells keeping people from flying into and out of Hogwarts till year 6.**

### Addition -

> ‘There are all sorts of enchantments on it, to stop
>   people entering by stealth. You can’t just Apparate in here.And I’d
>   like to see the disguise that could fool those Dementors. They’re
>   guarding every single entrance to the grounds. They’d have seen
>   him fly in, too. And Filch knows all the secret passages, they’ll
>   have them covered ...’

Here we have Hermione spelling it out fairly clear that the enchantments do NOT prevent people from flying in.

In year 1 Charlie Weasley’s friends fly in and out to take out Norbert.

> The steep spiral staircase up to the top of the tower seemed the
>   easiest thing in the world after that....About ten minutes later, four
>   broomsticks came swooping down out of the darkness. They showed Harry
>   and Hermione the harness they’d rigged up, so they could suspend
>   Norbert between them. They all helped buckle Norbert safely into it
>   and then Harry and Hermione shook hands with the others and thanked
>   them very much.

Year 2 we have the flying car fly into the grounds.

Year 3 we have Sirius Black flying out of Hogwarts on Buckbeak.

> He squeezed Buckbeak’s sides with his heels. Harry and
>   Hermione jumped back as the enormous wings rose once more ...
>   the Hippogriff took off into the air ... he and his rider became
>   smaller and smaller as Harry gazed after them ... then a cloud
>   drifted across the moon ... they were gone.

Year 4 the Beauxbatons carriage flew in.

> Something large, much larger than a broomstick – or indeed, a hundred
>   broomsticks – was hurtling across the deep blue sky towards the
>   castle, growing larger all the time... they saw a gigantic,
>   powder-blue, horse-drawn carriage, the size of a large house, soaring
>   towards them, pulled through the air by a dozen winged horses, all
>   palominos, and each the size of an elephant.

Year 5 Harry and crew fly Thestrals out of the grounds, and Fred and George fly out on broom.

> Harry did not think he had ever moved so fast: the Thestral streaked
>   over the castle, its wide wings hardly beating; the cooling air was
>   slapping Harry’s face; eyes screwed up against the rushing wind, he
>   looked round and saw his five fellows soaring along behind him, each
>   of them bent as low as possible into the neck of their Thestral to
>   protect themselves from his slipstream.

> And Peeves, who Harry had never seen take an order from a
>   student before, swept his belled hat from his head and sprang to
>   a salute as Fred and George wheeled about to tumultuous applause
>   from the students below and sped out of the open front doors into
>   the glorious sunset.

Finally, in year 6 we see the protections are added.

> “Alohomora!” he said confidently, pointing his wand at the padlock,
>   but nothing happened.
>
> “That won’t work on these,” said Tonks. “Dumbledore bewitched them
>   himself.” Harry looked around.
>
> “I could climb a wall,” he suggested.
>
> “No, you couldn’t,” said Tonks flatly. “Anti-intruder jinxes on all of
>   them. Security’s been tightened a hundredfold this summer.”

> Dumbledore muttering in some strange
>   language again. He thought he understood why as he felt his
>   broom shudder for a moment when they flew over the boundary
>   wall into the grounds: Dumbledore was undoing the
>   enchantments he himself had set around the castle, so that
>   they could enter at speed.

Comment: *Dumbledore counting on his hand the number of times flying things have gone in and out of the school*: "3....4.... Hmm... Perhaps we should put up some sort of barrier to stop this from happening, Minerva?" McGonagall: "That's what I tell you every year, Headmaster, but you never bloody well do it." And then of course, the only flying thing wanting in or out of Hogwarts during Year 6 was Dumbledore himself.

Comment: I'm not convinced that we can prove anything stronger than your first and last sentences. There's two instances of people *leaving*, which may not be subject to any enchantments. Presumably the Beauxbatons carriage (and Durmstrang ship, though it didn't fly) is explicitly expected. And if you concede that Harry and Ron were expected to be arriving that day, by whatever means, the strongest you can say is "year 1: no enchantments (Charlie), year 6: definitely enchantments (Dumbledore), other years: who knows?"

Comment: Actually I recall them suspending magical barriers and concealment charms to facilitate the entry of guest schools during *Goblet of Fire*. It'd be wrong to assume they just entered willy-nilly as Harry and Ron did on the Ford Anglia.

Comment: 4 would be keyed-in explicitly, 5 would be keyed-in implicitly (as school's property). Security could be tightened after year four when Dumbledore started believing that Voldemort came back.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I'd think that since it was a school full of 'upto-no-good' teenagers, of course they would want to prevent people leaving. It is as important as keeping out threats.

Comment: I could envision that Dumbledore knew exactly what Ron and Harry were up to and he could've dropped the barriers to let them in.

Comment: Great thinking and observation I should say @Himarm. Indeed we can to a great extent assume security measures were implemented later. But I think  Ghoti and Chips has a point about the security measures being suspended in _Goblet of Fire_.

Comment: @GeethikaAntony they have been. Ut goti and chips statements has no quote yet to back up his statement so while it is probably likely until i see a quote its still speculation

Comment: I was searching  _Goblet of Fire_ to support  Ghoti and Chips statement and couldn't find any yet. So I should say I agree with you @Himarm  and have accepted your answer.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo where exactly do Dumbledore and McGonagall have that conversation I cannot recall it. Could you give me the details.

Comment: @GeethikaAntony  im pretty sure disturbed is kidding

Comment: @Himarm Haha LOL.

Comment: I seem to recall a line somewhere about Hermione telling Ron/Harry that "you can't just apparate in and out of Hogwarts; it has all kinds of magical protections and enchantments!". Do you know when this happened?

Comment: @TylerH she says you cant apparate in and out of hogwarts like 10 times throughout the series. "honestly hasnt anyone read Hogwarts a history?"

Comment: If it's in that book the quote I'm recalling probably came from book 1 or 2... so wouldn't that indicate that there were protections in place before the events of book 6?

Comment: @TylerH apparating in and out, the fact that the castle is unplotable, muggle repelling charms, are all mentioned earlier, as ive shown weve seen people fly in and out for 5 years, and only with the Increased protections does flying seem to be limited.

Comment: @TylerH yes indeed as Himarm has mentioned, many times Hermione mentions about not being able to apparate or disapparate inside Hogwarts. But that is entirely different from flying in and out. That was possible we can see up to _Harry Potter and the Order Phoenix_

Answer (score 15):

During *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* the country was in the middle of a civil war. Any protections available would have been in place at full strength.

On the other hand during *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* story the country was at peace. Also, when Harry and Ron arrived in the flying *Ford Anglia* they were both individuals authorized and expected to be entering the school grounds on that day. It seems logical that the wards would allow them entry.

Comment: Also, Snape caught them after all. It's possible they set off an alarm anyway.

Comment: @Murphy Thank you for your comment.:)